# Acumatica - Revision

Tags: acumatica

We have 2 DAC - Master and Child

*Master DAC*

```
#region MasterID
public abstract class masterID:PX.Data.BQL.BqlInt.Field<masterID> { }
protected int? _MasterID;
[PXDBIdentity()]
[PXUIField(Visibility = PXUIVisibility.Invisible)]
[PXReferentialIntegrityCheck]
public virtual int? MasterID
{
    get {return this._MasterID;}
    set {this._MasterID = value;}
}
#endregion

#region MasterCD
public abstract class masterRoutingCD:PX.Data.BQL.BqlString.Field<masterCD> { }
protected string _MasterRoutingCD;
[BomID(DisplayName = "Master #", IsKey = true, Required = true,
    Visibility = PXUIVisibility.SelectorVisible)]
[PXDefault]
[Rev.Key(typeof(Setup.pMMasterNumberSequenceID),
         typeof(Master.masterCD),
         typeof(Master.revisionNo),
         typeof(Master.masterCD),
         typeof(Master.revisionNo)
    )]

public virtual string MasterCD
{
    get {return this._MasterCD;}
    set {this._MasterCD = value;}
}
#endregion

#region RevisionNo
public abstract class revisionNo:PX.Data.IBqlField { }
protected string _RevisionNo;
[RevisionIDField(IsKey = true, Visibility = PXUIVisibility.SelectorVisible,
    Required = true)]
[PXDefault(typeof(Master.defaultRevisionNo),
    PersistingCheck = PXPersistingCheck.Nothing)]
[Rev.ID(typeof(Master.defaultRevisionNo),
        typeof(Master.masterCD),
        typeof(Master.revisionNo),
        typeof(Master.revisionNo),
        typeof(Master.description),
        typeof(Master.fromDate),
        typeof(Master.toDate))]
public virtual string RevisionNo
{
    get {return this._RevisionNo;}
    set {this._RevisionNo = value;}
}
#endregion
```

*Child DAC*

```
public abstract class childID:PX.Data.BQL.BqlInt.Field<childID> { }
protected int? _ChildID;
[PXDBIdentity()]
//[PXReferentialIntegrityCheck]
public virtual int? ChildID
{
  get {return this._ChildID;}
  set {this._ChildID = value;}
}
#endregion

#region MasterID
public abstract class masterID:PX.Data.BQL.BqlInt.Field<masterID> { }
protected int? _MasterID;
[PXDBInt()]
[PXDBDefault(typeof(Master.masterID))]
[PXParent(typeof(Select<Master, Where<Master.masterRoutingCD, Equal<Current<masterCD>>,
    And<Master.revisionNo, Equal<Current<revisionNo>>>>>))]
public virtual int? MasterID
{
  get {return _MasterID;}
  set {_MasterID = value;}
}
#endregion MasterID

#region MasterCD
public abstract class masterCD:PX.Data.BQL.BqlString.Field<masterCD> { }
protected string _MasterCD;
[PXDBDefault(typeof(Master.masterCD))]
[PXDBString(IsKey = true, IsUnicode = true)]
public virtual string MasterCD
{
    get {return this._MasterCD;}
    set {this._MasterCD = value;}
}
#endregion

#region Revision
public abstract class revisionNo:PX.Data.BQL.BqlString.Field<revisionNo> {}
[PXDBString(15, IsKey = true, IsUnicode = true)]
[PXDBDefault(typeof(Master.revisionNo))]
public virtual string RevisionNo { get; set; }
#endregion Revision

public abstract class stepsID:PX.Data.BQL.BqlInt.Field<stepsID> { }
[OperationCDField(IsKey =true, DisplayName = "Steps ID",
    Visibility = PXUIVisibility.SelectorVisible)]
[PXDefault(PersistingCheck = PXPersistingCheck.NullOrBlank)]
//[PXUIField(DisplayName = "Process Steps ID")]
public virtual string StepsID { get; set; }
```

*Graph - MasterMaint*

```
public class MasterMaint:PXRevisionableGraph<MasterMaint, Master,
    Master.masterCD, Master.revisionNo>
{
    public PXSelect<Child, Where<Child.masterCD, Equal<Current<Master.masterCD>>,
        And<Child.revisionNo, Equal<Current<Master.revisionNo>>>>> ChildRecords;

    #region Override

    public override bool CanClipboardCopyPaste()
    {
        return false;
    }

    public override bool CanCreateNewRevision(MasterMaint fromGraph, MasterMaint toGraph,
        string keyValue, string revisionValue, out string error)
    {
        // Always returns true as new revisions can be created at any time
        error = string.Empty;
        return true;
    }
   
    public override void CopyRevision(MasterMaint fromGraph, MasterMaint toGraph,
        string keyValue, string revisionValue)
    {
        if(toGraph?.Documents?.Current == null || fromGraph?.Documents?.Current == null)
        {
            // api calls should create new revs on their own - this causes issues
            // when calling from api so we need to turn the copy rev logic off
            return;
        }
        toGraph.Documents.Cache.SetDefaultExt<EWPMMasterRouting.status>
            (toGraph.Documents.Current);
        if(SkipAutoCreateNewRevision())
        {
            return;
        }
        CopyChildRecords(fromGraph.Documents.Current.MasterRoutingCD,
            fromGraph.Documents.Current.RevisionNo, toGraph.Documents.Current.MasterID,
            keyValue, revisionValue, false);
    }

  
    internal virtual void CopyChildRecords(string sourceID, string sourceRevisionNo,
        int? newMasterID, string newMasterCD, string newRevisionID, bool copyNotes)
    {
        foreach(Child fromRow in PXSelect<Child,
            Where<Child.masterCD, Equal<Required<Child.masterCD>>,
                And<Child.revisionNo, Equal<Required<Child.revisionNo>>>>>
            .Select(this, sourceID, sourceRevisionNo))
        {
            var toRow = PXCache<Child>.CreateCopy(fromRow);
            toRow.MasterID = newMasterRoutingID;
            toRow.ChildID = null;
            toRow.MasterCD = newMasterCD;
            toRow.RevisionNo= newRevisionID;
            toRow = ChildRecords.Insert(toRow);
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Issue - When the value is changed in the Revision the record is displayed with new revision number keeping the CD fields as for previous revision and all the child.
That is all correct, But when the record is saved, there is error **"Another process has updated the Record, your changes will be lost"**
Why there is a Error

Comment: Hi Brian , thanks for your Editing

Comment: Brian, can you help me out to fix the issue,Here i think problemis with my Identity column that I have in bot Master and Child Table..
But dont know How to fix that

Comment: I didn't have a solid answer for you with any certainty, but I suspect it is in the graph portion.  I find that you should not give a child table an identity field, as a general rule.  You use PXDBIdentity when you make the field an Identity field in the database table, which you should avoid for a child record in most *common* cases.  The error you reported tends to hit me when I persist the record and then use a stale copy of the graph.  Typically the MasterCD field would not be in the child, but it doubt it would cause this problem.

Comment: I removed the Child table Identity column ,but still end up with same result.
I think it is the issue with PArent Identity column,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Acuamtica we have NoteID column unique across the system If you try to create a record with duplicating NoteID field value you'll get "Another process has updated the record" exception because it consider that you are updating the same record.
In you case when you copy revision you do not reset the NoteID value for the record so you actually try to insert another record with the same value.

You'll need to add the following line to CopyRevision method

```
toGraph.Documents.Cache.SetDefaultExt<EWPMMasterRouting.noteID>(toGraph.Documents.Current);
```